# VBA password accept numeric and text values

Tags: excel, vba

I have an access form contains `UserNameID` textbox and `PasswordID` textbox and `Login` Button which work very well with text only but when I enter password as number or character it shows a message says wrong password. So there is something missed or needs a correction in my code to recognize the characters or numbers.

Your assistance is highly appreciated here

```
Private Sub Login_Click()

Dim UserName As String
Dim Password As Integer
Dim FindRow  As Range

On Error Resume Next
If Me.UserNameID = "" Then
    MsgBox "you have to enter password"
    Exit Sub
End If

UserName = Me.UserNameID.Value
Password = Me.PasswordID.Value
Me.PasswordID.MaxLength = 14
Me.PasswordID.PasswordChar = "*"

'find the name of the employee written on the search box in column A
Set FindRow = Sheets("Login Information").Range("A:A").Find(what:=UserName, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not FindRow Is Nothing And Me.PasswordID.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
    PayrollandStaffMainForm.Show
Else
    MsgBox "The Password you entered is wrong, please try again"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: by the way, I defined the Password as integer, variant, string, long but the same result

Comment: Are you sure the cell value is a string? If not, then you could be trying to compare a numeric data type with a string from your textbox. `Me.PasswordID.Value = CStr(FindRow.Offset(0, 1).Value)`.

Comment: Step1: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. Step 2: set a breakpoint in your code and see what it is doing.

Comment: many thanks Shai, it works well after I added CStr. for the second option I do not know how to do the breakpoint but anyways, I successfully got what I want to be seen, so please make it as full code to be able to mark it as answered. thanks boss

Comment: You should really learn how to do a breakpoint - it'll make debugging easier in future. Here: I saved you a dozen keystrokes on google: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php